# Exclude Folder redirection GPO for specified computers

Tags: windows, folder-redirection

I'we set-up a GPO for folder redirection wich works fine.
Now i would like to achieve that this policy would not be applied to specific computers. 
It's supposed to be done with another object:

Computer configuration->Administrative templates->System->Group policy -> UserGroupPolicyLoopbackMode(Replace)

Within this second object the user configuration side for folder redirection is left untouched, so if i understood the help, this should override the first object and not redirect users documents folders.
This is not working for me, why?

btw. the GPO's were made from Win7 client machine, and the one i would like to exclude from applying folder redirection is XP client.

Comment: Is the GPO that is not configured for folder redirection linked to the OU where the computers that you don't want folders redirected on are?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Problem was in the order of GPO's applied. After i moved the second GPO to apply first, all is working fine. Makes sense, doesn't it.